# How do you navigate an array of image file objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, object, navigation

I am tasked to create navigation buttons for a simple image processing application, that navigate through a folder containing images. I am required to create an array of file objects of a selected folder.

The buttons have to be **next** and **previous** buttons, that navigate the next image within the array of file objects. After the last image within the folder was reached, the next button has to loop to the first image and vice versa with the previous button.

I tried declaring an `int[]` array of the length of the number of files contained within a folder using the `listFiles()` method, but I received the error: *cannot find symbol*:

```
int[] file = new int[("/pictures").listFiles().length];
```

What would I need to do in order to be able to create an array of file objects of the length of the total number of files, which I would be able to navigate using buttons?

Comment: Your problem is calling `listFiles` on a String, rather than a File object

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is calling `listFiles` on a `String`, rather than `File` object. Try to modify your code as follows:

```
int[] file = new int[new java.io.File("/pictures").listFiles().length];
```